# How can I configure session in my WCF service called from windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, windows-phone-7

I have a service which is being called from WP7. I know WP7(Silverlight) only supports basicHtptBinding till today and unfortunately it doesn't support Session so I can't use InstanceContextMode.PerSession and SessionMode.Required in this service. But I have some data on server which I need to be preserve it on session basis. What options do I have?

Comment: If you provide us an example of what kind of data you think needs to be persisted via the Session, we could make better suggestions.

Comment: There is one login method, which instantiates an object of 3rd party SDK and logs me in that 3rd party system. There are other methods also which use the 3rd party object instiantiated in login method. However as nothing is preserved, I can't use that object created in login method. Oh and yes! I can't make this call to 3rd party directly from wp7. So please do not suggest that option.

Comment: How long does the login method take for the 3rd party SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Windows Phone 7 programming, but if it will allow you to use basicHTTPContextBinding, which is a flavor of basicHTTPBinding, then I suggest you look into a Durable Service.

Durable services allow you to save session state in some persistent storage and access it with each new method call via a token.

Take a look at the blog article at this [link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/egady/archive/2008/01/05/wcf-3-5-durable-services.aspx).

Even if you can't create a formal Durable service, you may be able to create something with a similar idea - pass a token (login/userid or something) and read state from persistent storage - database table or something.

Let us know if you get it working!

Comment: Your solution looks promising. I will try it on Monday and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ConcurrentDictionary in a static class on the server-side to cache the object using the user's identity as a key.  If you need the cache around for a very long time, you'll want to host the service in a Windows Service, to avoid issues with app pool cycling, etc.

Comment: And how will the items be removed from that Dictionary? On what basis should I remove? or let the dictionary keep growing?

Comment: Depends on how many users you have.  If it's not many, then yeah, you can just let it keep growing.  If it's a lot, then you'll want to wrap the object in a class that also contains a DateTime indicating when you put the element in the cache.  Then you can run a background task on a timer that says:  if the element has been in there for x period of time, remove from the dictionary.

Comment: Could also use ASP.NET build in Cache:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx